# before_filter in Rails and ajax requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the app based only on ajax calls but i need constantly to check the decreasing value in session variable. I created a before_filter with a `redirect_to :action => :action_name` for some reason this doesn"t work for me. I see in log `Filter chain halted as [:method_name] rendered_or_redirected.` but in fact nothing happens. 
Does anyone know what's the problem? I wanted to make the code DRY with using filters but looks like it's not handling ajax requests :(

The code is pretty simple (it's a game actually)
here's the method which hangs on before_filter

```
def check_winner
  if session[:game].user.cards.length == 0 || session[:game].pc.cards.length == 0
    flash[:notice] = "The end"

    redirect_to :action => "win"
  end    
end
```

session[:game] keeps several objects that I initialize at the beginning of the game. I've never used rails filters with ajax but it worked always with normal http requests
The user triggers actions everywhere via `link_to_remote` I tryed to render ajax page update on the filter method but it just throws me doble render error :(

Comment: can you see the before_filter code ?

Comment: `redirect_to` actually gives a redirect (302) to the browser, this is probably not what you want. You need to be more specific as to what you're trying to do. Also please post code. We'll need pretty much all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to redirect in the before_filter are you using that to redirect to an AJAX-specific action? A better alternative is to either use a responds_to block to respond to specific requests or to simply have an ajax-specific url that gets called.